# How to solve $^2−(4+)−10−10=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the equation is: $$^2−(4+)−10−10=0$$

I've tried to use the quadratic formula, but still can't get the solution.

I need an algebraic number form.

Thank you for help!

Comment: What goes wrong when you use the quadratic formula?

Comment: Please show where you are facing difficulties with the quadratic formula.

Comment: "i" does not go from under the root

Comment: Why should it?  You will certainly need to extract the square root of a complex number.

Comment: After using the quadratic formula I get $((4+i)±sqrt(48i+55))/2$

Comment: Hint:  $55+48i$ has a fairly simple square root.  Just solve for it.

Comment: You have $\sqrt{48i+55}$ in there, true. What's the problem, though? Complex numbers have square roots too, you know.

Comment: But with root form of number won't be algebraic

Comment: @АлександрЛисов it would be. Roots of complex numbers are complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminant is
$$
(4+i)^2-4(-10-10i)=16+8i-1+40+40i=55+48i=64+48i-9=(8+3i)^2
$$
How do you establish the last equality? I did it by educated guess, but you can always do the standard way: if $(a+bi)^2=55+48i$, then
\begin{cases}
a^2-b^2=55 \\[1ex]
2ab=48
\end{cases}
so $b=24/a$ and $a^2-576/a^2=55$. Solve the biquadratic.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

Comment: @PeterPhipps Yes, typo fixed,

Answer (score 1):

Using the quadratic formula: $$z=\frac{-4-i\pm\sqrt{(4+i)^2-4(-10-10i)}}{2}\\z=\frac{-4-i\pm(8+3i)}{2}\\\Rightarrow \begin{align}\boxed{z_1=2+i\\z_2=-6-2i}\end{align}$$ This gives the polynomial $$(z-2-i)(z+6+2i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$48i+55 = 64+48i-9 = 64+48i+9i{^2 }= (3i+8)^2$

Then you have that :

$\sqrt{(55+48i)}=\sqrt{(3i+8)^2 }= 3i+8$

With this you can find the roots $-2-i$ and $6+2i$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you say you have $\sqrt{48i+55}$.

If $(a+bi)^2 = 55 + 48i$ then $a^2-b^2 = 55$ and $2ab=48$.

$a = \frac{24}b$ so

$\frac{24^2}{b^2} -b^2 = 55$

$24^2 - b^4 = 55b^2$

$b^4 +55b^2 -24^2 = 0$

$b^2 = \frac {-55\pm\sqrt{55^2 + 4*24^2}}2=$

Well, calculator time

$55^2 + 4*24^2 = 5329=73^2$

$b^2 = \frac {-55\pm 73}2 = -64, 9$.  As $b$ is real $b^2 \ge 0$ so

$b^2 = 9$ and $b = \pm 3$ and $a= \frac {24}b= \frac {24}{\pm 3} = \pm 8$.

So $\sqrt{48i + 55} = \pm (8+3i)$.

......

So

$z=\frac {(4+i) \pm (8+3i)}2 = \{6+2i, -2-i\}$

......

Alternatively.   If we assume that whoever wrote this question wanted simple integer answers (ha!)

We'd have:

$a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) = 55 = 5*11$ and $2ab =48=2^4*3$ so $ab=2^3*3$

Assuming integers and as $a+bi$ is square root if and only if $-a-bi$ is, and as $ab$ is positive, we know $a,b$ are the same sign and we can assume it is possitive.

$a-b,a+b = 1, 55$ or $5, 11$.  so $a,b=28,27$ or $8,3$.  As $8*3=24$ but $28*27\ne 24$, we have $a,b = 8,3$ and $8+3i$ is one square root and $-8-3i$ is the other.

But that was hoping there would be a nice integer answer.

=====

There's also the technique of $a^2 - b^2 = 55$ so...hey the next couple of squares bigger than $55$ are are $64$, $81$, $100$ etc and minus $55$ we get $9$ and ... well $9$ is a square.  If $a=8$ and $b=3$ do we get $24$.  ... why, yes!  Yes we do.

Heck... there's probably even a graphing calculator where you can graph $x^2 - y^2 =55$ and $xy=24$ and see where they intersect.